# Which Open Source Cloud Management Platform supports Amazon-RDS?

Tags: cloud, amazon-rds, eucalyptus, opennebula

I have been trying to use Amazon Web services, specially EC2 and [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/). Nowadays most CMP (Cloud Management Platform) like Eucalyptus, OpenNebula, OpenStack, Nimbus and CloudStack all support Ec2 to a certain level, some do it better than others.

But when it comes to Amazon's RDS service I just can't seem to find any information. It's like no CMP supports it. On my research I came across a website that suggests the use of third-party software like HybridFox, RightScale and enStratus to have an RDS like support but I don't get it.

Can someone tell me if Eucalyptus, OpenNebula, OpenStack, Nimbus and CloudStack support RDS?

If not, then how I can I use third-party software to access Amazon's RDS service using the previously mentioned CMPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of my experience I can tell stratoscale provide such option. Basically they've got this SDDC solution called Symphony, and their cloud is Openstack based. Latest version of symphony allows you to utilize both your private cloud and AWS as on-premise. I can testify I have never encountered such strong scalability. If you're dealing with large amounts of data that could be a nice option for you since I found it effective when it comes to reducing costs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of listed platforms they all support EC2 to some extend but not RDS.

RightScale supports RDS as listed here (http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Regions/RDS_Instances/Concepts/About_RDS_Instances) in all regions provided by amazon. But you' ll still need to sign up for the service. To create new RDS instance, please, look to RightScale documentation (http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Regions/RDS_Instances/Actions/Create_a_New_RDS_Instance).

I can also advice using Amazon Cloud Watch as it will require no additional payment apart from payment for using resources.

Comment: But Rightscale is payed with real money (iirc), which I can't afford. This is why I need an open-source solution. I discovered currently that there is [reddwarf][1] for openStack but's that's all I've got. I would really need more :S

[1]:https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Reddwarf